# Missing key property with dynamically generated react-bootstrap components

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have stumbled accross suspicious behaviour and I am not sure whether the error is on my end, or this is a react-bootstrap bug.

When I am creating navigation dynamically, I am getting followig error

`` main.js:2331 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Header`. See ... for more information ``

This error disappears if I define the `key` properly, but AFAIK this should not be needed, because `eventKey` should take care of this

Example of code:

```
render() {
    let routes =[
        {
            name : 'Dashboard',
            path : '/',
        },
        {
            name : 'Navigation Manager Tool',
            path : '/tools/navigation-manager',
        }
    ];

    return (
        <Navbar inverse className="widget-header">
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Nav activeKey={this.props.active.path}>
                    {
                        routes.map((route) => {
                            return (
                                <NavItem eventKey={route.path} href={route.path}>{route.name}</NavItem>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

Notice that following works without any problem

```
render() {
    return (
        <Navbar inverse className="widget-header">
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Nav activeKey={this.props.active.path}>
                    <NavItem eventKey="/" href="/">Dashboard</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey="/tools/navigation-manager" href="/tools/navigation-manager">Navigation Manager Tool</NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

Comment: try storing the results of the map and then output them with {routes}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`key` and `eventKey` are different properties. The have nothing in common.

The `key` should always be supplied if you create array of components.

[React docs about key](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children).